# Inno Setup (How to get dynamically path to file)?

Tags: path, installation, inno-setup, dynamically-generated

I'm making a setup script in Inno and I was wondering, how can I get non "hardcoded" path. Here is example:

[image: Image, which contains patch source]

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION:**

You can get .iss folder by using predefined variable

> SourcePath

Usage would be like: {#SourcePath}\???\bin\x86\Release\???.exe

Thanks all who contributed!

Comment: `#define MyAppName "MY APP"
#define MyAppExeName "my_app.exe"

[Files]
Source: "{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}\SOURCES.PROJECTS\???\???\Release\{#MyAppExeName}"`

Comment: @RobeN if I run this script from other computer and lets say that the folder is not on Desktop, this would not work right?

Comment: `{userdesktop}` constant always points the real desktop of current user - no matter what language version of Windows is installed. In Polish it would be e.g. `C:\Użytkownicy\MOJ_PROFIL\Pulpit`

Comment: Yes I understand that @RobeN. Now I'm asking you, how to get a script folder. Lets say that my install script (.iss -> script) is located in Desktop/SOURCES.PROJECTS/???/InstallScript.iss.
Now I want to achieve "Desktop/SOURCES.PROJECTS/???/". I found one solution here already, but its not working for me. Thanks btw.

Comment: There's no need for preprocessor variable here. You can use relative paths.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reference about the [`source directory`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=sourcedirectorynotes) says (emphasized by me):

> **By default, the Setup Compiler expects to find files** referenced in the script's [Files] section Source parameters, and files referenced
>   in the [Setup] section, **under the same directory the script file is
>   located if they do not contain fully qualified pathnames**. To specify
>   a different source directory, create a SourceDir directive in the
>   script's [Setup] section.

This includes also option to specify relative path to the files. So let's assume that you have the following file structure and you didn't specify a different path in the [`SourceDir`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_sourcedir) directive:

```
C:\Deploy\Script.iss
C:\Deploy\MyProg.exe
C:\Deploy\SubFolder\MyOtherProg.exe
C:\Folder\SomeFile.txt
```

Now if you'd like to include the `MyProg.exe` into the setup compiled from the `Script.iss` script, you could specify just the file name without the path, since the `MyProg.exe` file is stored in the same folder as the script, so you could write just:

```
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

And you can use a relative path to the `MyOtherProg.exe` which is stored in the subfolder of the folder where the `Script.iss` script is stored this way:

```
[Files]
Source: "SubFolder\MyOtherProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

As well as you can use a relative path to include the `SomeFile.txt` stored in a subfolder of the parent folder where the script is stored:

```
[Files]
Source: "..\Folder\SomeFile.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

More about relative path conventions you can read in [`this chapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths).

Answer (score 2):

Like OP has said in his own question,

> You can get .iss folder by using predefined variable
>
> `SourcePath`
>
> Usage would be like: `{#SourcePath}\???\bin\x86\Release\???.exe`