# dynamic path in INI-File called by inno-setup

Tags: inno-setup, ini

I need to get a path name from an INI-file. I already know how to read a INI-file and asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096018/can-i-put-setup-command-line-parameters-in-a-file-which-is-called-during-install). This helped me a lot. Right now I am confused by dynamic paths. I run another program from within the setup, which works perfect. The path to this other program is written within my INI-File, it looks like this:

```
[setup]
FileOfOtherProgram="C:\Users\desktop\somefile\Other Program.exe"
```

This works. What I need right now is a dynamic path like this:

```
FileOfOtherProgram="..\somefile\Other Program.exe"
```

Which does not work but throws the following error:

```
Unable to execute file:
..\somefile\Other Program.exe

CreateProcess failed; code 267.
The directory name is invalid.
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620729/inno-setup-how-to-get-dynamically-path-to-file) question and answer on stackoverflow as well, which told me that it should work.

EDIT: I normally run the setup with `/SILENT`. When I tried it without this is what I got. On the wizard-page where I normally should enter a path for the `Other Program.exe` the path from the INI-file is pre-set. This works fine with normal fully qualified paths. But with the dynamic path I still get the exact string from the INI-file which would be (as sugeestet by S.Spieker) `{src}\..\somefile\Other Program.exe`

I can't figure out what to change to make this work, can you tell me what I did wrong or tell me that it is impossible?

Comment: It depends to which directory is that path relative. If it's relative to the directory from which the user executes the setup, then @S.Spieker's answer is correct.

Comment: @TLama I'm not sure if I got that right, but the setup.exe would be in `C:\Users\desktop\someotherfolder\setup.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add the base dir from where you want to get one folder up.

For example:

```
FileOfOtherProgram="{src}\..\somefile\Other Program.exe"
```

Comment: That sounds great! Took my some time to figure it out completley though. I had to put the `GetIniString(..)` within in `expandConstant()` Now it works. THANK YOU!